# C delete linked list node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I write linked list in C

the first created node's next (`node->next`) is `NULL`

and last created node is HEAD.  (reversing order)

I create 3 nodes `a, b, c`

and I want remove the `b` node

Here is my code:

```
struct node {
    char *name;
    void *data;
    int size;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;

void remove_data(Node *node, char* d_name) {
    
    while (node != NULL) {
        // remove data from heap
        
        if (strcmp(node->next->name, d_name) == 0) {
            node->next = node->next->next;
            printf("remove %s\n", node->next->name);
            printf("%s -> %s\n", node->name, node->next->name);
            free(node->next);
            break;
        } else {
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

and call this function `remove_data(head, d_name);`
I predicted this program prints

```
remove b
a -> c
```

but it prints

```
remove b
b -> b
```

Why is that?

Comment: Just as a side note: Why are you comparing the string `d_name` with `node->next->name`? If the head node contains the text you are searching for, you will never find it. Why not compare with `node->name` instead? Also, if `remove_data` removes the head, it needs some way of passing the new head to the caller.

Comment: Please complete a complete example. You are not showing your node/list structures, you are not showing, how you build the list.

Comment: @lulle: You are probably looking for `[ m r e ]` (without spaces). It expands to this: [mre]

Comment: Ah, thanks. how come i didn't know about that haha. Anyway, as mentioned by AndreasWenzel, if you use compare to 'node->next->name' you a) will never find the text if 'head' contains it and, arguably even worse, b) 'node->next' might be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function in any case does not make a sense.

First of all it ignores the name stored in the first (head) node due to the comparison

```
strcmp(node->next->name, d_name) == 0
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function may not be called for a list that contains only one node.

After this assignment

```
node->next = node->next->next;
```

the pointer to the node that shall be deleted is lost.

Also it is unclear what these data members

```
    void *data;
    int size;
```

mean and whether you need also to free the memory pointed to by the pointer `data`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown below. The function definition is based on your function definition. If it is required then you should also insert the statement

```
free( current->data );
```

before

```
free( current );
```

Here is the function definition.

```
int remove_data( Node **node, const char *d_name )
{
    while ( *node != NULL && strcmp( node->name, d_name ) != 0 )
    {
        node = &( *node )->next;
    }

    int success = *node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *current = *node;
        *node = ( *node )->next;
        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}
```

You have to pass a pointer to the pointer to the head node to the function when you will call the function.

That is the pointer to the head node must be passed by reference. In this case  if the deleted node will be the head node then the original pointer to the head node will be updated.  Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the pointer to the head node and changing the copy will not influence on the value stored in the original pointer.

Comment: In case OP does not know the difference between [call by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) and [call by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm), I am providing these links.